# Is a Python Queue needed for simple byte stream between threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a simple thread that grabs bytes from a Bluetooth RFCOMM (serial-port-like) socket and dumps them into a `Queue.Queue` (FIFO), which seems like the typical method to exchange data between threads.  Works fine.

Is this overkill though?  Could I just use a bytearray then have my reader thread `.append(somebyte)` and the processing function just `.pop(0)`?   I'm not sure if the protections in Queue are meant for more complex "multi-producer, multi-consumer queues" and a waste for a point-to-point byte stream.  Doing things like flushing the queue or grabbing multiple bytes seem more awkward with the Queue vs. a simpler data type.

I guess the answer might have to do with if `.pop()` is atomic, but would it even matter then?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Queue`, you're *guaranteed* to be threadsafe in any implementation and version of Python. Relying on this or that method of some other object being "atomic" (in a given implementation and version) typically leaves you at the mercy of this "atomicity" not being a strong guarantee (just an implementation artifact for the specific point release &c you're using) and therefore subtle, VERY hard-to-debug race conditions being introduced with any upgrade or port to other Python implementations.

If your profiling tells you that `Queue`'s strong and general guarantees are being a bottleneck for your specific producer-consumer use case, make your own simpler guaranteed-to-be-threadsafe FIFO queue/stream. For example, if you've found out that (net of race conditions) `append` and `pop` would be perfect for your use, just make a class that protects each with a lock acquire/release (use a `with` statement) -- `Queue` adds miniscule overhead to support multiple producers and consumers and you can shave those few nanoseconds off!-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pop() is atomic, but I'd stick with Queue if performance is not super important.

Answer (score 0):

If the rate of input is fast enough, you can always buffer bytes up into a string before pushing that onto the Queue. That will probably increase throughput by reducing the amount of locking done, at the expense of a little extra latency on the receiving end.